# windows hostname command returning chinese characters

Tags: windows, command-prompt, hostname

I'm currently trying to use the hostname command in a batch script in windows 7 to append the hostname of a computer to a text file on a remote server.  Here's what I'm using:

hostname >> \\remoteserver\directory\textfile.txt

When I run that, all I get in the remote file are some chinese characters that google can't translate - though running this appends the hostname correctly in English:

hostname >> c:\users\user\desktop\textfile.txt

Anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: what about My computer properties is there correct host name or same Chinese chars

Comment: You don't say how you're opening the file to check the contents. There are some programs that try to guess the encoding of a file based on the first few characters, and they can guess wrong if given certain combinations of characters. Does the hostname contain any non-ASCII characters?

Comment: The hostname is in alphanumeric, english characters.  Nothing non-ASCII.  And I'm just opening the file with notepad.  Nothing fancy or sophisticated.

Comment: Notepad is one of those programs that tries to guess an encoding. Don't know why it would guess incorrectly with pure ASCII input though.

Comment: It works perfectly as long as the file is located on the local system.  It only does this when I specify a file to be appended on a remote server.  Other stuff appends just fine to the remote file, i.e. ipconfig and other commands that print output.  It's just hostname that does this.

Comment: Seems to be the [Bush hid the facts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bush_hid_the_facts) bug but this was solved in Windows Vista and later. Did you have a look at the binary output of the text file? And what's the locale of the remote server?